# External project references are not copied to output directory

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core

So I've few projects in my solution, which uses also some external projects. Unfortunately those external project are not copied to output directory.

`Project-1` - written in .net framework 4.5.

`Project-2` - same as above, .net framework 4.5.

`Project-A` - written in .net standard 2.0. Has references to both, `Project-1` and `Project-2`. After build, `Project-1` and `Project-2` can be found as *.dll in output directory. This is fine.

`Project-B` - written in .net framework 4.8. Has reference only to `Project-A`. Unfortunately, here only `Project-A` is copied, without `Project-1` and `Project-2` assemblies which results in error *FileNotFound*.

What is the proper solution here? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Please, share the details of your solution and `csproj` files

Comment: What kind of details? I cannot put whole csproj here, unfortunately.